# How to change Java path used by Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I recently compiled my code using `Java 1.8`. I had set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` to do the compilation using `ant`

Now, When I start Eclipse (Luna), in order to debug application using Tomcat plugin for eclipse. I starts using below path - using Java 1.7

[image]

And tomcat starts and prints below

```
Apr 10, 2018 4:25:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Apr 10, 2018 4:25:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 10, 2018 4:25:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Apr 10, 2018 4:25:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
```

**How can I use Java 1.8 in this ?**

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project > Java Build Path > Libraries

Remove java 1.7 library and "Add Library..." for java 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Proceed to the Tomcat server instance configuration and set Tomcat Runtime Environment JRE  to "Workbench Default JRE".
[see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHPkD.jpg)

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: I don't find any such setting. Can you tell me how to navigate to that ?

Comment: @SimpleGuy At first ensure that you're using Java EE perspective in Eclipse, in other case switch to it. Then go to the 'Servers' tab, double click on your tomcat instance, the 'Overview' windows will appear, click a link "Runrime Environment" and in the appeared window 'Edit Server Runtime Environment' choose a JRE from drop-down list. Hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

Comment: I did that already.. doesn't reflect. Even restarted eclipse after that